# Azure PowerShell vs Azure CLI; creating an ACI OWASP ZAP container issue

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cli, owasp

I am trying to set up an automated DAST scan via Azure Powershell and hosted in the Azure cloud. I want to use Azure powershell as it gives me a bit more control and integration possibilities.

The Azure CLI I have working :

```
rem Create the container
call az container create -g %ACI_RESOURCE_GROUP% -n %ACI_INSTANCE_NAME% --image owasp/zap2docker-stable --ip-address public --ports 8080 --azure-file-volume-account-name %ACI_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME% --azure-file-volume-account-key %STORAGE_KEY% --azure-file-volume-share-name %ACI_SHARE_NAME% --azure-file-volume-mount-path /zap/wrk/ 
--command-line "zap.sh -daemon -host 0.0.0.0 -port 8080 -config api.key=abcd -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true"
```

However doing it in Azure Powershell, a bit more commands are required, but I :

```
$volume = New-AzContainerGroupVolumeObject -Name "owasp-dast-volume" -AzureFileShareName $storageAccountShareName -AzureFileStorageAccountName $storageAccountName -AzureFileStorageAccountKey (ConvertTo-SecureString $key -AsPlainText -Force)
$mount = New-AzContainerInstanceVolumeMountObject -MountPath "/zap/wrk/ " -Name "owasp-dast-volume"
$container = New-AzContainerInstanceObject -Name $AzureContainerInstanceName  -Image owasp/zap2docker-stable 
-Command 'zap.sh -daemon -host 0.0.0.0 -port 8080 -config api.key=abcd -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true'
#

New-AzContainerGroup -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name 'owasp-zap-cg' -Container $container -Volume $volume -location $location  -IPAddressType 'Public' -OSType 'Linux'
```

It appears as to be failing because of the command argument in Azure Powershell, which is the exact same as it is in the Azure Cli, but in PowerShell

```
z.ContainerInstance.internal\New-AzContainerGroup : CodePackageActivation:owasp-zap-scfobt2:EntryPoint:133186770245706206'. 'There was an error during CodePackage activation.GrpcStatusCode=UNKNOWN, 
ErrorMessage=failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: failed to create container fadcb85315c2a29c90a44973cc69e550fa8752257b408d399fcdbb759740b956: guest RPC failure: failed to create 
container: failed to run runc create/exec call for container fadcb85315c2a29c90a44973cc69e550fa8752257b408d399fcdbb759740b956 with exit status 1: container_linux.go:380: starting container process 
caused: exec: "zap.sh -daemon -host 0.0.0.0 -port 8080 -config api.key=abcd -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown'
;The container group provisioning has failed. Refer to 'DeploymentFailedReason' event for more details.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Az.ContainerInstance\3.1.0\custom\New-AzContainerGroup.ps1:315 char:7
+       Az.ContainerInstance.internal\New-AzContainerGroup @PSBoundPara ...
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ({ SubscriptionI...    ]
  }
} }:<>f__AnonymousType9`4) [New-AzContainerGroup_CreateExpanded], UndeclaredResponseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OK,Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ContainerInstance.Cmdlets.NewAzContainerGroup_CreateExpanded
```

I really have no idea what I am doing wrong, as it appears that Powershell complains over  the zap.sh file missing on the container, but I am using the same image (and version) that I really dont see the issue. If someone could enlighten me where I am going wrong that would be amazing

Comment: Try specifying the full path to the shell script, eg `/zap/zap.sh`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed a step.
You create the volumemountobject, but then you don't use it in the containerinstance object, so it doesn't know where to reference

Yours

```
$container = New-AzContainerInstanceObject -Name $AzureContainerInstanceName  -Image owasp/zap2docker-stable 
-Command 'zap.sh -daemon -host 0.0.0.0 -port 8080 -config api.key=abcd -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true'
```

Microsoft Docs
[Powershell docs for az continer commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.containerinstance/new-azcontainergroup?view=azps-9.4.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-9.2.0) - reference the mountpoint created with the -VolumeMount parameter

```
$container = New-AzContainerInstanceObject -Name test-container -Image alpine -VolumeMount $mount
```

The docs then create the container group

```
$containerGroup = New-AzContainerGroup -ResourceGroupName test-rg -Name test-cg -Location eastus -Container $container -Volume $volume
```